# The proper and clear way to manage external resources in D with Derelict and SDL

Tags: sdl, d, raii

I'm following through an SDL tutorial series (written in C++) using Derelict and D.  So far the conversion has been simple, but one element of the tutorial writers style bothers me and I've been trying to figure out the best way around it. But my knowledge of D isn't the best, so I'm not sure hwo to handle this.

Essentially, to use SDL, I must load image files into memory as SDL_Surfaces.  Before the program exits, these surfaces need to be manually freed using SDL_FreeSurface().  This seems like an ideal case for `scope(exit)` and indeed it does work very well... for loading and unloading resources in the span of a single function.  But ideally I'd split all that up so that one function handles the loading and then somewhere else another function frees them.  And then beyond that maybe each resource just handles itself.  I guess that's RAII but I don't really understand how to use it in D.

I thought you just set up a new class to carry the resource, load it in `this()` and free it in `~this()` but it seems I read that the destructor isn't guaranteed to be called unless you instance the class as `scope`.  I could use a struct I guess, but it seems like I'd be missing out on useful benefits of classes if I did.

What I want is to load resources and get guarantees about them being freed, but to do so in a sane manner that doesn't require me putting all loading and unloading into one huge method.  How should I approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that - at least on platforms featuring an operating system with multitasking - you don't need to worry about clean-up when your application exits.

Alternatively, you could simply store said resources in a global set.

Comment: It's possible that some resources could be maintained external to the process, e.g. on the video card, as a file or over a network. OTOH I'd consider that a bad design for the resource. That said, a global set sounds like a good idea.

Comment: +1 to what CyberShadow says. @BCS - it is not a bad design, system guarantees that it will cleanup the mess after application exits. It is a very strong guarantee, and millions of developers rely on it.

Comment: I think I figured out my dilemma with scope(exit) being limited to within the function by (obviously) moving it higher up.  So now the main "run" function calls `scope(exit){clean_up();}` which maybe isn't super elegant but nicely covers my case of assuring cleanup gets done for everything.

Comment: I'm confused about two points though.  1) I don't understand your first statement, are you talking about the GC?  My impression was the if you didn't call SDL_FreeSurface() then the memory stays used.  Are you saying that this is the case, but doesn't matter because the OS will handle it?  2) Wouldn't using global resources be global variables and, therefore, bad?

Comment: 1) All memory is still allocated in the address space of the application. The operating system is responsible to clean up all used kernel resources (memory, handles / file descriptors), e.g. in the event that the application terminates unexpectedly (crashes). Anything else would make it a poor operating system. Drivers responsible for hardware resources are tasked in similar ways.

Comment: 2) Don't blindly follow best-practices advice without understanding the reasoning behind them. In your case, such resources match the lifespan of the application, therefore the use of static/global variables is adequate here. Note that you don't need to put them in the global visibility scope - you could encapsulate them as static fields in a resource manager class, for example.

Comment: @DejanLekic, I was pointing out that (in the more general case) there could be resources where the system doesn't or even can't guarantee that it will cleanup the mess after the application exits. The doesn't case is IMHO a bad design and the can't case could be if there are alternatives where it can.

Comment: It's like leaving all your mess on your desktop and expect the cleaning lady to run through your garbage at the end of the day. There are so many points we programmers do just for consistency, not always for essence. I think you should always be consistent with allocations and deallocations. It gives your finer control and knowledge about the code; you KNOW the scope of the data. Everything is modularized. If you program OO, proper deallocation is a free benefit.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to automatically free the SDL_Surface you should just wrap SDL_Surface in a struct and take advantage of RAII. It's a good fit for this type of thing. Just be sure to disable postblit to avoid double freeing or implement reference counting.

```cpp
struct SurfaceRAII
{
    this(SDL_Surface* surf_handle)
    {
        m_handle = surf_handle;
    }

    // disable default constructor and postblit (no copies)
    @disable this();
    @disable this(this);

    ~this()
    {
        SDL_FreeSurface(m_handle);
    }

    public SDL_Surface* m_handle;
}
```

Untested but that's the general idea.

Edit: You could also use std.typecons.RefCounted on a class if you'd prefer.

Comment: Aside from automatic clean-up, RAII doesn't give you anything over scope(exit).

Comment: I guess that's true with a postblit disabled RAII struct.  A reference counted RAII object offers some more flexibility, I think.